# MS Access 2003 - VBA for altering a table after a "SELECT * INTO tblTemp FROM tblMain" statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I use functions like the following to make temporary tables out of crosstabs queries.

```
Function SQL_Tester()
Dim sql As String

If DCount("*", "MSysObjects", "[Name]='tblTemp'") Then
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblTemp"
End If

sql = "SELECT * INTO tblTemp from TblMain;"

 Debug.Print (sql)

  Set db = CurrentDb
  db.Execute (sql)

End Function
```

I do this so that I can then use more vba to take the temporary table to excel, use some of excel functionality (formulas and such) and then return the values to the original table (tblMain). Simple spot i am getting tripped up is that after the Select INTO statement I need to add a brand new additional column to that temporary table and I do not know how to do this:

```
sql = "Create Table..."
```

is like the only way i know how to do this and of course this doesn't work to well with the above approach because I can't create a table that has already been created after the fact, and I cannot create it before because the SELECT INTO statement approach will return a "table already exists" message.

Any help? thanks guys!

Comment: This sounds like a problematic design. First off, you shouldn't be creating tables in your application's front end. Second, a task that is repeated shouldn't constantly require altering the destination table's structure. Occasionally, sure, but not as a matter of course. Nail down the import format and you can avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: this is actually for an automation piece that calls to financial functions in excel through a temporary access app from mine that gets created, with tables made from queries that mine provides to it. However, what was causing a problem was to get the 'behind the curtain excel' approach to work, the results come back to the table. So I needed the empty fields to be created in this on the fly approach and sending the resulting data fields to display on forms (of my actual database), or ppt automated presentation, etc. Its because this excel idea really works, but this is the only way I know...

Comment: ...how to get it to work, because I learned this excel utilization trick from the cookbook for access. i also have a custom add in built into excel through a buffet of class modules that give me the ability to create sparkline graphs with formulas in excel. so i believe i can get the above concept to work with the graphs as well (it just basically creates them as shapes, not MS Graphs) just need to find out how to return an OLE.copy method to a form instead of rs.fields....if it does great, if not oh well. I understand what you are saying, this is all just very atypical automation stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of the following ways you can achieve this

**1. Create, then insert**

You can do a `CREATE TABLE tblTemp` with all the columns you need. Of course, you will have more columns than TblMain contains, so your insert will contain column definitions.

`INSERT INTO tblTemp (Col1, Col2, Col3) SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 from TblMain`

**2. Insert Into, then add column**

You can do your insert into, then add columns using multiple ways

1. In VBA, use the `TableDef` object to point to tblTemp and then add a column to it
2. Execute `DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE tblTemp Add Column MyNewColumn` (OTTOMH)

Answer (score 1):

There always more than one way to skin a feline.  You could use DAO?  This has the advantage of being able to set the various properties of the newly created field that get when creating new field via the user interface within Access.  Just an idea :-)

This the sub l created and tested, in Access 2007 should be compatable with any version though.

```
Public Sub AddField()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Dim strTable As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb

strTable = "tblTemp"

'create the TableDef object that
'wish to change
Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(strTable)
'create new field
Set fld = tdf.CreateField("Name", dbText)
'set property of new created field
fld.AllowZeroLength = True
'append the new field to the tabledef
tdf.Fields.Append fld

End Sub
```